# How to implement areas in Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I'm going to design and develop a website with Asp.net webapi and AngularJs.

I need a suggestion for separating the admin area and the user interface of the site.

In previous project I got help from mvc area and create admin in an mvc area.

A friend also suggested that I can create two Angular projects separately with one webapi service.

whats your idea ????

If there is any problem, tell me.

If I need to read an article, suggest me

Do I need use Ui Router ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Angular project separately which can be used with Production by the building project. To create the server on the client side you can use gulp, webpack which very useful tools to create a client-side project.

You can see demo project here 
https://github.com/frederikprijck/angularjs-webpack-starter